# Flow trace/audit trail data for instance on weblogic EM not available

Tags: soa, weblogic12c

I am trying to get the audit trail data through the flow trace for an instance of a web service composite on weblogic EM  but getting the following error:

Error while processing audit information. Failure due to Exception fetching audit xml.

[image]

I need to retrieve the data for this flow instance i.e. the input payload for this instance

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

In my case, the problem was the audit trail was bigger than the default value in EM.

The link which helped me to solve it is **[this](http://waslleysouza.com.br/en/2014/11/exception-huge-audit-trail-soa-suite/)**. The link is from `11g`, but the property is the same.

Since the Link is broken, I´m pasting the solution from the blog:

Exception occured while retrieving the Flowtrace XML for the Composite Instance; ECID: 2d0237859052c116:-7239f8e2:1495cf2793d:-8000-0000000000002db1

> > java.rmi.RemoteException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is:
> >
> > > ```
> > > java.lang.RuntimeException: oracle.soa.management.facade.DataSetTooLargeException: Requested audit trail size is larger than threshold 1048576 chars
> > > ```

This happens because the instanceTrackingAuditTrailThreshold parameter is used to limit the audit trial size. It prevents huge audit trails to potentially consume a lot or all the memory available on the SOA server. The default value of instanceTrackingAuditTrailThreshold parameter is 1MB.

Go to Enterprise Manager and expand the Farm and SOA nodes. Right-click the soa-infra (AdminServer) node and choose SOA Administration > Common Properties.
In the SOA Infrastructure Common Properties page, click the More SOA Infra Advanced Configuration Properties link.
In the System MBean Browser page, click the AuditConfig link.
In the Attribute: AuditConfig page, increase the value of instanceTrackingAuditTrailThreshold parameter.

[image]

Comment: The link provided is not accessible anymore. Found backup in https://web.archive.org/web/20190403152351/https://waslleysouza.com.br/en/2014/11/exception-huge-audit-trail-soa-suite/ . The solution briefly tells to change instanceTrackingAuditTrailThreshold parameter into from "SOA Administration -> Common Properties -> More SOA Infra Advanced Configuration Properties (bottom link) -> Click on ‘Audit Config’ attribute from the list"